# The Abysmal King

Tags: riddle, word, knowledge, rhyme, poetry

What was the king's name (missing from the riddle), 
but more interestingly, what was the king trying to hide?

> Slay me now, and take a solemn vow, 
> Men can't say I might have died this way, 
> Thrust me through, and make it strong and true. 
> I'm a wreck, but long live the king __________.

HINT 1:

> The kings name is more than one syllable.

HINT 2:

> The riddle is in reference to an event described in an old famous book.

HINT 3:

> The title contains an alliteration for his name: `Abysmal ________`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think the answer is

> [Abimelech](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abimelech_(Judges))

What was the king trying to hide?

> At the Battle of Thebaz, Abimelech comes upon a heavily fortified tower. The civilians head towards the top of a tower while he fights his way through. Abimelech successfully fights most of the way towards the tower, however, a woman struck his head with a stone above. Realizing the wound was mortal, he ordered his armour-bearer to thrust him through with his sword, so nobody would know he was killed by a woman.

Also,

> It rhymes with wreck.

Comment: I was trying for way to long to try and get it to rhyme with "way" because I didn't recognize the rhyming scheme XD

Comment: @samm82 Yeah the third and ninth syllables rhyme of each line. I was hoping it still read well though. Obviously an exception was made for the king's name, but I thought that was acceptable considering it was a last word and missing... hence the puzzle. :-)

Comment: I tried to make Shrek work, not even close 

Comment: Dumb question from a newb, how do you go about solving this sort of thing if you lack biblical knowledge?

Comment: @personaelit It is [knowledge](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/knowledge) puzzle as well which means it does rely on external knowledge. So anything with that tag implies it is targeted to anyone who happens to have knowledge in that area.